# Give me best possible loop to iterate in sql with performance

Tags: sql-server

suppose i have two table and both tables consist of one date column eg

```
OUTTime
12:05:40
12:08:30
12:20:40
```

and other table consist of

```
INTime
12:10:35
12:12:23
12:16:40
12:30:11
```

Now i want rows with Minimum time difference between two tables like 12:08:30 and 12:10:35 gives me OUT and IN. Similarly 12:20:40 and 12:30:11 gives me another row here by eliminating OUTTime 12:05:40 and eliminating 12:12:35 and 12:16:40 from INTime which gives me proper OUtTime and InTime

Any suggestion how to loop to get this data?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the data ?

Comment: Don't use loops at all but set approaches(`SELECT ... WHERE ...`).

Comment: I'm really having a hard time understanding what output you want exactly. Could you please add a sample output based on the dataset?

Comment: Does not make much sense. _"with Minimum time difference between two tables like 12:08:30 and 12:10:35 gives me OUT and IN."_ Must `INTime` be always after `OUTTime`? It would help if you'd show the desired output with some more sample rows.

Comment: Looping/procedural code is the LAST thing you want to do, 99% of the time.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a matching InTimes and OutTimes and only get the closest, try this:

**Set Up**

```
CREATE TABLE #OUTTime
(
    [Time] Time
)

INSERT INTO #OUTTime
    VALUES
        ('12:05:40'),
        ('12:08:30'),
        ('12:20:40')


CREATE TABLE #InTime
(
    [Time] Time
)

INSERT INTO #InTime
    VALUES
        ('12:10:35'),
        ('12:12:23'),
        ('12:16:40'),
        ('12:30:11')
```

Now the query:

```
;WITH CTE
As
(
    SELECT O.Time AS outTime, (SELECT MIN([Time]) FROM #InTime I WHERE I.[time] > O.[Time])  AS InTime
    FROM #OUTTime O
)
SELECT MAX(OutTime) As OutTime, InTime
FROM CTE
GROUP BY InTime
```

**Results**

```
OutTime             InTime
12:08:30.0000000    12:10:35.0000000
12:20:40.0000000    12:30:11.0000000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you UNION the two tables ... something like

SELECT Time, 'IN'
   FROM InTimesTable
UNION
SELECT Time, 'Out'
   FROM OutTimesTable
Order by Time

You can dump it in excel, and manipulate it manually.

Or, you can fill out your question here, and get a better answer.